# twitter bootstrap 2.3.0 modal transition is not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
.modal-confirm.modal.hide.fade
div.modal-header
    button.close(data-dismiss='modal') x
    h3
div.modal-body
    p
div.modal-footer
    button(data-dismiss="modal").cancel.btn Cancel
    button.submit.btn Ok
```

javascript:

```
$('#login-form #forgot-password').click(function(){ $('#get-credentials').modal('show');});
```

this used to work very well, but i upgraded to twitter-bootstrap 2.3.0 and the modal does not appear in the middle of the window anymore, it is stuck at the top of the window. 
jquery 1.8.0 version

[image]

Comment: make sure you did not click on the modal when you are trying to "inspect element" in chrome. It breaks the positioning of bootstrap. Assuming you're using chrome.

Comment: Cant really help with out a test page to see the exact issue you are having . Please post a test page or a jsfiddle

Comment: The same code worked well with jquery1.8.0 + bootstrap2.0.4 and now upon upgrade to bootstrap 2.3.0 does not work. no code change, just pulled in the upgrade from: netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: i looked at differences in bootstrap-min.css, v2.0.4 and v2.3.0 and modal.fade.in{top:10%} in 2.3.0 and it was modal.fade.in{top:50%} in 2.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i looked at differences in bootstrap-min.css, v2.0.4 and v2.3.0 :

```
modal.fade.in{top:10%} in 2.3.0 
and 
modal.fade.in{top:50%} in 2.0.4
```